# randint(0, x/2) вызывает ошибку: ValueError: non-integer stop for randrange()

Tags: python, python-3.x, случайные-числа

Подскажите, пожалуйста, функция random в каких случаях может принимать условием переменную? К примеру я пытаюсь написать алгоритм в котором я загадываю диапазон от 0 до x, затем ввожу число n в этом диапазоне и компьютер пытается угадать это число number. Примерно так:

```
x = int(input ("Введите число которое будет окончанием диапазона"))

number = int(input ("Введите число которое будет угадывать компьютер в введенном диапазоне"))
guess = 0

import random
while number != guess:
    guess = random.randint(0, x/2)
    if guess > number:
            x= x + x/2
    elif guess < number:
            x = x - x/2
print ("Done!", guess)
```

Естественно получаю ошибку, так как randint в данном случае не подходит. А что подходит?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`randint` принимает только целые числа, так что используйте целочисленное деление – `x//2`

```
x = int(input ("Введите число которое будет окончанием диапазона"))

number = int(input ("Введите число которое будет угадывать компьютер в введенном диапазоне"))
guess = 0

import random
while number != guess:
    guess = random.randint(0, x//2)
    if guess > number:
            x= x + x//2
    elif guess < number:
            x = x - x//2
print ("Done!", guess)
```